# GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion `GST_IS_MINI_OBJECT (mini_object)' failed

Tags: c++, gstreamer, openframeworks

I have a vector of [ofPtr](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/types/ofPtr.html) (shared pointer) items that point to objects containing videos, in form of [ofVideoPlayer](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoPlayer.html) objects. When the videos are done playing ('dead' variable set to true) i delete them and their reference by calling `erase()` on the vector.

```
vector<ofPtr<videoElement> >::iterator iter = videos.begin();
while (iter != videos.end()) {
    (**iter).update();
    if ((**iter).dead) {
        iter = videos.erase(iter);
    } else {
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

The program runs fine (or seems to), yet every time the erase function is called, i get this output:

> GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion
>   `GST_IS_MINI_OBJECT (mini_object)' failed

I don't seem to get these output lines when i clear the whole vector at once with `videos.clear()`, which confuses me over if this is a gstreamer or pointer issue.

Also, I've tried with different video files and different codecs (H264, animation, photoJPEG) yet all show the same output line.

As the output line hasn't led to any actual problems yet, i am not too concerned, but i would like to understand where this is coming from.

System:
Linux, Ubuntu 12.04, Openframeworks with codeblocks (of_v0.8.0_linux64_release)

Comment: Please explain what is the thing you call "video files" ? Are they GstCaps ? or GstBuffers ?

Comment: They are instances of the ofVideoPlayer class. Looking through the source code, i think they are build on top of GstCaps.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`. Normally this error is caused by invoking `xxx_unref(some_obj)` on an object you actually don't own, and that call will finally invoke `gst_mini_object_unref()` for deconstruction of components of your object. Just in case anyone is still bothered by this error ...

Answer (score -3):

There is a known bug in GStreamer related to this which, in theory, should be fixed by installing `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`.

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GStreamer)

Comment: Even the main developer of gstreamer emphasized not using gstreamer 0.10 dozen of times.

Comment: This question (and answer) is almost ten years old, so I'm not sure how relevant it is anymore.